# GraphQL.Net v5 and .Net 6 Installation

Tags: .net-6.0, graphql.net

Has anyone successfully implemented GraphQL.NET v5 in .NET 6 and been able to register in Program.cs as there is no Startup.cs?  There are breaking changes from V4.

[This is the message I get after upgrade to v5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkoh0.png)
regards,
Olafur

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have but I am using latest version 7.3.0 with .NET 6 Installation, the signature for AddGraphQL has changed as below, the sample code in Program.cs in .net 6.

```
AddGraphQL(Action<IGraphQLBuilder>? configure)

builder.Services.AddGraphQL(builder => builder
.AddSystemTextJson()
.AddSchema<SampleSchema>()
.AddGraphTypes(typeof(SampleQuery).Assembly)
.AddErrorInfoProvider(opt => opt.ExposeExceptionDetails = true)
.AddDataLoader());
```